# How to get an object with certain type using C# Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I have Generic list holding root objects means I have:

```
public class Component  
{  
}  

public class DBComponent : Component  
{  
}  

private List<Component> components;
```

I want to get a list with only the DBComponent references using Linq. means something like that :

```
List<DBComponent> dbComponents = components.FindAll(c => c is DBComponent);
```

However, it does not seems to work
Please can someone provide working Linq code?
Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for

```
IEnumerable<DBComponent> dbComponents = components.OfType<DBComponent>();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<DBComponent> dbComponents = components.OfType<DBComponent>().ToList();
```

Comment: The point being he wants a list of DBComponents from a list with objects of a super class type.

Comment: I mean, the point of the unit test. It's just a bunch of noise that hides your real answer, which is `components.OfType<DBComponent>().ToList()`.

Comment: Actually, you're right minitech.. ..was about to delete my answer, but it was actually the correct answer since liorafar wanted it as a list. Thanks for making your point.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this, even if your code *seems* to be valid one too.

```
var result = components.Where(c => (c as DBComponent)!=null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
components.OfType<DBComponent>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) or [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method. The key difference is that `Cast` throws an exception, if the Enumerable contains any element that cannot be cast to the target type. `OfType` doesn't throw this exception, but just skip elements of those types.

In different scenarios both these methods can be handy, so it's up to you to choose. If you want just to filter your Enumerable by some Type, `OfType` is what you need, I guess.